# Type error when using useReducer in combination with array destructuring

Tags: reactjs, typescript

useAuthService.tsx

```js
import { createStore } from 'reusable';
import { useReducer, useEffect } from 'react';

export type AuthenticationState = {
    user: any,
}

export type AuthenticationAction = {
    type: 'UPDATE_USER',
    payload: any,
}

const initialState = {
    user: null,
}

const reducer = (state: AuthenticationState, action: AuthenticationAction) => {

    switch (action.type) {
        case 'UPDATE_USER':
            return { ...state, user: action.payload };
        default:
            throw new Error();
    }
}

export const useAuthenticationState = createStore(() => {
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);

    return [state, dispatch]

})
```

Inside this file the state has the type of `{user: any;}` and dispatch variable has the `React.Dispatch<AuthenticationAction>`. But when using them in a component typescript throws a error in VSC.

Auth.tsx:

```js
const Authentication = () => {
    const [state, dispatch] = useAuthenticationState();

    return (
            <div className="bg-red-500 text-white">
                {state.user?.email}
            </div>
    );
};
```

When trying to use 'user' from the state Typescript throws a error:

```
Property 'user' does not exist on type '{ user: any; } | Dispatch<AuthenticationAction>'.
  Property 'user' does not exist on type 'Dispatch<AuthenticationAction>'.ts(2339)
```

It renders though. Using VSC with Typescript 3.8.3.

Comment: you need to provide how you are handling your redux state, because you're using redux right ?

Comment: Nope, no redux. Using reusable to turn custom hooks to global hooks. But even without the global functionality the problem persists. So not really relevant for the example I think.

Comment: Can you show what your `reducer` and `initialState` look like or at least what type they have?

Comment: @Aron I've updated the codeblock.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why `createStore` can't infer what its type parameter should be by looking at the return type of its function, but regardless you can help it along by passing the type parameter to it explicitly:

```
const useAuthenticationState = createStore<[AuthenticationState, any]>(() => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);

  return [state, dispatch]
})
```

In this example I've set the type parameter to be `[AuthenticationState, any]`, because I want it to return a tuple with two members, the first of which is your `AuthenticationState` Now that it knows this you can safely access `state.user` in your React component.

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgYygUwIYzQZRtNOAXzgDMoIQ4BydAVwGcMAjAGzWoChRJY4AlTMhgAaRHEZpBAEzrI0UYmQpVaQmNQDcnTmgAeveDACeYQgEE6MABZoAdjGDIswCHbxZCAXkSc4EhgUALjgMO2MRTiIdfUM4EzM4Sxt7R2dHN3NhVzs4HwQ-eNM0EOoAVQAFABFzABUAUQB9Mpx6-mpI-zAMY1YIDGkQsIionWQ3BnhgO2BHDFYPbDzff0koELs6VlZI6M5xu0m4dFl5RR8ACknPEOTbBycXN0W0MQxst1ure7SnuyyMnYAJR5AB8vkKDAA7rNkNY4Bd3oCAHQJNAggr%20fzOQI0So1BrNVrtIKFLHHNAwOhQXJIZH067YMRrIYfOzI7q9frSYjacnSNCkDBbGCk8n%20GwUKFwOxoaX1KAUKAXIF84ijGIGaDwA5HSR3VKPQEvZaoTDYPAEAA8AG0DQ90jkXm9wgBdUEXFVglYoCbwG2M15waTABjdGBw13LSQyOQKC4nONQMTTWbAeYvVU6fzoKk0uABmCeMQhsNYSNRIE6fZ%20pLfQ2OtzLL1ecGY32Hf2Bkuh8OR6OBe2-Y1F7Aq7SFXPU3IXMlwK0hgBuKFYGAYDAAchgQGgvAAiZgAcwAtCdjwBWAAMl-i%20hgx6h1lmaD3oLn-gQgeRawA-Mi0CAGDAKw0TklaAD0S5vv4WZEJoQA)

Answer (score 0):

By default typescript uses union types for arrays; since you want tuples you have to specify the return type of useAuthenticationState:

```
export const useAuthenticationState = createStore((): [AuthenticationState, React.Dispatch<AuthenticationAction>] => {
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);
    return [state, dispatch]
})
```

You can avoid all of this by not destructuring in the first place; React will do it for you:

```
return useReducer(reducer, initialState);
```